# BeautifulSoup - Table

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-table

On the website below there is a table called "tbListaOpc"

https://opcoes.net.br/opcoes/bovespa/ABEV3

I tried but was unsuccessful in retrieving the information from this table.
Can anyone help me figure out how to read all the rows in this tbListaOpc table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selenium` combined with `pandas` in order to scrape the table:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

url = 'https://opcoes.net.br/opcoes/bovespa/ABEV3'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2)

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="grade-tipo-items"]/label[1]').click() -- uncomment this line to click on the CALLs button

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="grade-tipo-items"]/label[2]').click() -- uncomment this line to click on the PUTs button

time.sleep(0.5)

dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)

driver.close()

df = dfs[-1]
columns = [col[0] for col in list(df.columns)]
df.columns = columns

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Ticker  Tipo   FM Mod.  ...   Gamma Theta ($)  Theta (%)    Vega
0   ABEVW958   PUT  NaN    E  ...   424.0     -55.0    -2750.0  1669.0
1   ABEVK100  CALL  NaN    A  ...     NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
2   ABEVW100   PUT  NaN    E  ...   691.0     -71.0    -2367.0  2417.0
3   ABEVW105   PUT  NaN    E  ...  1118.0     -82.0    -2050.0  3302.0
4   ABEVK110  CALL  NaN    A  ...   417.0     -49.0      -18.0  2062.0
5   ABEVW110   PUT  NaN    E  ...  1978.0    -120.0    -1500.0  5315.0
6   ABEVK115  CALL  NaN    A  ...  2742.0    -220.0     -259.0  8315.0
7   ABEVW115   PUT    ✔    E  ...  2897.0    -192.0     -914.0  8149.0
8   ABEVK120  CALL    ✔    A  ...  3385.0    -235.0     -452.0  9582.0
9   ABEVW120   PUT    ✔    E  ...  5170.0    -145.0     -580.0  9531.0
10  ABEVK125  CALL    ✔    A  ...  3446.0    -214.0     -764.0  9249.0
11  ABEVW125   PUT    ✔    E  ...  3242.0    -221.0     -316.0  9319.0
12  ABEVK130  CALL    ✔    A  ...  2740.0    -176.0    -1173.0  7495.0
13  ABEVW130   PUT    ✔    E  ...  2705.0    -174.0     -166.0  7618.0
14  ABEVK135  CALL    ✔    A  ...  1909.0    -131.0    -1638.0  5405.0
15  ABEVW135   PUT  NaN    E  ...  1725.0     -71.0      -50.0  4050.0
16  ABEVK140  CALL    ✔    A  ...  1216.0     -87.0    -2175.0  3520.0
17  ABEVW140   PUT  NaN    E  ...   771.0     -22.0      -12.0  1736.0

[18 rows x 17 columns]
```

You can also export these values to a `csv` file by using the `to_csv` function:

```
df.to_csv('D:\\Values.csv',index=False)
```

Screenshot of `csv` file:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I more question. In this website there is a checkbox where we can select one option ("Calls", "Puts" or "Todos"). Also there are checkbox where we can select check one or more option. Is it posible to check this option before call the url?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Which checkbox(es) do you want to check?

Comment: I want to ckeck the option "Calls" or to check "Puts" but never "todas". Also if posible i want to select one or more dates (avalaible in label "Vencimentos")